# Unable to acquire intent filter from ResolveInfo instance

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-package-managers

I have a list which contain apps that can handle any of my two actions `Intent.ACTION_PICK` and `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. i later on use an array adapter to populate my listivew with the information from this list.

In my `onItemClickListener`, am able to acquire `ActivityInfo` and `ComponentName` from `ResolveInfo` instance.**but am not able to get**  `IntentFilter` instance from `ResolveInfo` (**attempt to get it throws NullPointerException**), **AND YET** any application that is in my list **MUST HAVE** resolved **one of my intents for it to be ln the list**

This is the line throwing nullpointerexception `IntentFilter filter = launchable.filter;`

```
private void acquirePicture(){

ListView lv=(ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();

List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivityOptions(
this.getComponentName(),new Intent[]{takePicture},
photoPickerIntent,0);

Collections.sort(launchables,
        new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

appAdapter=new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ResolveInfo launchable=appAdapter.getItem(position);
        ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
        ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                activity.name);

IntentFilter filter = launchable.filter;
            if(filter.actionsIterator() != null){
                Iterator<String > actions = filter.actionsIterator();
            }

            int actioncode;
            Intent  intent = new Intent();
            Uri uri;
            if(filter.hasAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK)){
                actioncode = 1;
                uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                intent.setData(uri);
            }else{
                actioncode = 0;
            }
            intent.setComponent(name);
            startActivityForResult(intent,actioncode);

    }
});

}

class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> {
private PackageManager pm=null;

AppAdapter(PackageManager pm, List<ResolveInfo> apps) {
    super(Custom_chooser.this, R.layout.row, apps);
    this.pm=pm;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView==null) {
        convertView=newView(parent);
    }

    bindView(position, convertView);

    return(convertView);
}

private View newView(ViewGroup parent) {
    return(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false));
}

private void bindView(int position, View row) {
    TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

    label.setText(getItem(position).loadLabel(pm));

    ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).loadIcon(pm));
}
}
```

**Question**

How can i get the intent(s) which the selected app resolved in my onClickListner body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly say that you want the filter returned. Instead of:

```
List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivityOptions(
    this.getComponentName(),
    new Intent[]{takePicture}, photoPickerIntent, 0);
```

Use this:

```
List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivityOptions(
    this.getComponentName(),
    new Intent[]{takePicture}, photoPickerIntent,
    PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
```

I haven't actually tested this. Please be aware that there are a lot of bugs and missing functionality related to returning `IntentFilter`s. In a lot of cases the documentation is wrong, in a lot of cases the code just doesn't do what you would expect it to do, and there aren't a lot of good working examples.

Try this and let us know if it works.

Comment: i don't really understand the 2nd and 3rd parameters of `queryIntentActivityOptions()` what am doing is guess work. i din't understand them well from android documentation since there wasn't even an example. do you understand this method well?

Comment: for the answer, it's perfect. worked well. i highly appreciate your help. i din't understand well the 3rd parameter in `queryIntentActivityOptions()` **that's why i was putting a zero**. please give me feedback on my previous comment(one above).

Comment: Some fields of the `ResolveInfo` are not filled in by default; the `GET_` constants must be used to request them.

Comment: @gikarasojokinene For some reason I didn't see your comments. Sorry about that. Basically @j__m provided the answer. The third argument is a set of flags. You need to specify, using these flags, which information you want returned in the `ResolveInfo` objects, as by default a lot of information is not returned.